# How to pass a value to "data-value"

Tags: javascript, html

I have website: http://thanglongvn.com with this in my webpage

I have a label on the same web page. I would like the "data-value" to get the value from the label value instead of hardcode value.

How to do that? How I can pass a value programmically to "data-value" and define the html mark-up as blank like this:

```
<div class="counter-animated" data-value="span dynamic value here"></div>

<span id="my_IDLabel">dynamic value</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. . show us some working snippet or fiddle so we could help you out.

Comment: What worked for you...please let us know and consider accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set a data attribute programatically like so

```js
var label = document.querySelector('.value')
var target = document.querySelector('.target')
var output = document.querySelector('.output')

output.innerHTML = target.getAttribute('data-value')

document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    target.setAttribute('data-value', label.textContent)
    output.innerHTML = target.getAttribute('data-value')
  })
```

```html
<label class="value">Bar</label>
<div class="target" data-value="Foo"></div>

<br/>

<button>change data-value attribute</button>

<br/><br/>

The data-value attribute is:
<br/>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access data attributes using plain javascript as element.dataset.datasetname

In this case,it is element.dataset.value,you can set it as element.dataset.value="class1"

check this snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var counterClass = document.querySelectorAll('.counter-animated');
  
alert(counterClass[0].dataset.value);
 counterClass[0].dataset.value="class1";
}
```

```html
<div class="counter-animated" data-value="span dynamic value here"></div>

<span id="my_IDLabel">dynamic value</span>
```

Hope it helps